# Server error 500 after copying website

Tags: php, wordpress

Today I had to copy a website (wordpress) from one server with cPanel and Linux to another server with Plesk and Linux. Both PHP 5.6 so I figured everything should go well. It didn't. The wordpress itself including plugins are fine and both set up on the new server, unfortunately the made their own theme and that's where it's all going wrong.

At first there was a function which made the whole site crash with an internal server error. Got that fixed eventually by erasing the function and just made it return a preset statement but there errors keep going in. At this point I have no idea what to do anymore.

The next code is also gives a internal server error 500

```
<div id="artists">
        <?php
        $count = 1; 
        $paged = 1;
        $postsPerPage = 15;
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        query_posts( 'post_type=artist&orderby=title&order=asc&paged=' . $paged . '&posts_per_page='.$postsPerPage );

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'label'); if( !empty($terms) ) { $term = array_pop($terms); $label_logo = get_field('logo', $term); } ?>

        <a class="artist <?php if($count%3 == 0) { echo ' last'; } ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" <?php if($label_logo) { ?>style="background-image: url(<?php echo $label_logo; ?>);"<?php } ?>>
            <h3 class="artist_name"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail('artist'); } else { ?><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/img/placeholder_artist.jpg" alt=""><? } ?>
        </a>

        <?php $count++; endwhile;?>
    </div>
```

with error:

```
    AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.nl/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/hardnews/_artists.php on line 27\n', referer: http://www.xxxxxxx.nl/
```

Somewhere in WHILE loop there is a malfunction but I just can't see the problem. Does anyone see a clear problem or has any idea what the problem might be, different PHP settings or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So start debugging. Remove lines of code and find which one causes error.

Comment: @u_mulder I did, I already fixed a couple, the one above is a WHILE I just can't seem to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?` is disabled by default I believe. Have you enabled this on your new server?

In php.ini:

`short_open_tag=On`

Then restart apache.

**or better yet**

Change it to `<?php`

Comment: Thank you! Completely missed that after 30 hours of being awake. Changed everything to <?php and it works, there was a lot... Thanks again!